# Changing name of Virtual Button after instantiating new ones

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

So, I am trying to create a function that Instantiates a virtual button in Vuforia Unity.

This Virtual Button contains a `panel` and a `3d Text`. It is the child of an ImageTarget.

So far I managed to Changed the name of the game object but what I can't seem to get around is changing the Virtual Button Behaviour Name.

[image]

For instance, I want to change the Name 'Test' to 'Test1'

```
void genLevel(Hashtable level)
    {
        int min = 1;
        int max = level.Count;

        //inputButtons = new GameObject[level.Count];

        System.Random rnd = new System.Random();

        IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(min, max).OrderBy(r => rnd.Next());

        foreach(int i in numbers)
        {
            string output = (string)level[i];
            Debug.Log(i + " " + output);
            var temp = Instantiate(vb, new Vector3(-0.0056f, 0.001f, 0.4547f), Quaternion.identity, parent.transform);
            temp.name = "Button" + i.ToString();
            temp.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().name = "Button" + i.ToString();
        }

        Destroy(vb);
    }
```

I tried accessing the VirtualButtonBehavior Script by creating a `public VirtualButtonBehaviour sc`.

After trying to access the Name by writing the line `temp.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().name = "Button" + i.ToString();`

The following error popped up:

> 'VirtualButtonBehaviour' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no accessible extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'VirtualButtonBehaviour' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I also referred to the Vuforia Documentation [How to Create and Modify Targets in Native](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Access-and-Modify-Targets-at-Run-Time.html#virtual-buttons).

What is the best way to go about it?

Comment: as the error said, it seems that virtual button does not define a setter for name, VirtualButtonBehaviour has only a getter for the name `public string VirtualButtonName { get; }`.  the virtual button itself has only a setter for area, enable and sensivitity

Comment: also if you are calling .name, instead of .Name, you are trying to change the property of UnityEngine.Object

Comment: This sounds like a **Typo**. The error states you are trying to set `Name` but in your code you showed here it is `name` .. which would be the inherited property [`Object.name`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html) of the `VirtualButtonBehaviour` component (which is basically just a forwarder to the according `GameObject.name`)

Comment: Would you please explain what's missing or what did not work for you in my answer, I'd like to know what I did not cover ? Please use the comment feature at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Edit original content still valid.

[According to the documentation](https://library.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/references/unity/classVuforia_1_1VirtualButtonBehaviour.html), they expose the name through `string VirtualButtonName => mName` but it seems it might only be a setter.

Not clear if the class `VirtualButtonName` is `Sealed`, `Internal`, if not you can inherits from it and create your own SetName function.

=====

I do not know Vuforia Unity, but I know you are probably facing one of those 2 cases.

There are 2 way in which VirtualButtonBehavior could have defined their Name field, the one you see in the inspector, assuming that the class inherits directly from MonoBehavior.

1st potential implementation

```
public class VirtualButtonBehavior : MonoBehavior
{
    public string Name;
...
```

With this approach, you should be able to do the following (using your code sample)

```
var buttonBehavior = temp.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>();
buttonBehavior.Name = "Button" + i.ToString();
```

First notice the upper case `.Name` that I used, if you use `.name` on any MonoBehavior, this will points to the GameObject name on which your component VirtualButtonBehaviour is attached to and not to the Name property of the VirtualButtonBehaviour.

2nd potential implementation

```
public class VirtualButtonBehavior : MonoBehavior
{
    [SerializedField]
    private string Name;
...
```

In this case you are out of luck, because Unity draw automatically public field in their inspector if the class inherits from MonoBehavior.

This is actually a good practice of encapsulating your code a private field combined with the `[SerializedField]` tag, in which it will draw in the editor but won't be modifiable by code outside of the VirtualButtonBehavior class.

However, with this approach you can only modify it in the editor once the component is attached to a GameObject.

One workaround, could be that you create a subclass of VirtualButtonBehavior and you implement a new Field that you wish to keep track of.

```
public class CustomVirtualButtonBehavior : VirtualButtonBehavior 
{
    public string MyName;
...
```

Then you can set dynamically your value using the following instead.

```
var buttonBehavior = temp.GetComponent<CustomVirtualButtonBehavior>();
buttonBehavior .MyName = "Button" + i.ToString();
```

Before going that route, make sure they did not expose a public function to set their name.

```
var buttonBehavior = temp.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>();
buttonBehavior.SetName("Button" + i.ToString()); // is this something they provided?
```

Finally, there might be a third way if they were kind enough to set their Name field scope to `protected` you could use it in a subclass and create your own `SetName` function.

Comment: The script is not accessible. So when it comes to changing the name, there isnt a SetName only a GetName Function.

Comment: @AnthonyMifsud You mean the Class is Sealed or internal so you cannot inherits from it?

Comment: Yeah, i cannot inherit from it.

Comment: @AnthonyMifsud wow, disappointing, why they would prevent such things. Oh well, in that case you are at their mercy, not much you can do with that class. sadly.

Comment: I ended up, manually creating the virtual buttons my self.

Comment: @AnthonyMifsud yeah I would have done the same at the point, or recode that class using the next level of inheritance. Otherwise, you could have attached a custom MonoBehavior to track the name, but that's far from ideal, not very efficient.